# Configure file outside of xampp in vhost

Tags: apache

I have lost my local vhost configuration for this app.
The index.php file is outside of the xampp folder because of reasons.
How do I configure my vhost so I can access this index via my-app.local?

I've already tried multiple things but it always just shows me the index of the xampp htdocs folder...

```
<VirtualHost my-app.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\MyApp\App"
    ServerName my-app.local
    <Directory "E:\MyApp\App>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\backoffice\public"
    ServerName dev.backoffice.local
    ServerAlias 192.168.2.21
    <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\backoffice\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I did have this working before, but honestly don't know how I did it...

Comment: Confirm location of index.html file?

Comment: The index.php is right there in E:\MyApp\App

Comment: Change `<VirtualHost my-app.local:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Restart Apache httpd service and test. Also make sure that each VirtualHost contains ServerName. If you are accessing `http://my-app.local` then ServerName should be `my-app.local`.